# how to config Adhoc for Xcode 3.2.4?

Tags: xcode, adhoc, entitlements

it not show the same as old version it only uncheck get-task-allow

in this version show like this how i config it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new entitlements-file anymore. If your testers have iOS4 or later, try this:

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

You just have to choose the correct provisioning-profile for your build and go. This allows you to share your apps with testers/clients without sending them the actual files, but only a URL to open in Safari on their phone and install through there. (Still requires their UDID in the provisioning tho).

At least, that's all I had to do. :)